# Problems trying to compare two negative numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function below, i am trying to compare negative numbers, I'm using unix time so the time difference is negative because the date has already passed, but I still want to use it, when the within5Days variable is a negative four(-4) the within5DaysBoolean variable is not set to false, it is still being set to true, I don't know what I'm missing here, any help

```
function timeDifference2(next, now) {
    var sPerMinute = 60;
    var sPerHour = sPerMinute * 60;
    var sPerDay = sPerHour * 24;
    var sPerMonth = sPerDay * 30;
    var sPerYear = sPerDay * 365;
    var sPerTwoDays = sPerDay * 2;

    var elapsed = next - now;
    return Math.floor(elapsed / 3600);
}


var within5Days = timeDifference2(unixTime, currentUnixTime);
if (within5Days < 120 && within5Days > -2) {
    var within5DaysValue = within5Days;
    var within5DaysBoolean = true;
} else if (within5Days > 120 || within5Days < -2) {
    var within5DaysValue = within5Days;
    var within5DaysBoolean = false;
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the `sXxxXxx` variables that don't seem to need to be there: what makes you think this is occuring?

Comment: what's the input you are using for `unixTime` and `currentUnixTime`?

Comment: also, please remove unnecessary lines from your code; none of those `sPer..` variables are used.

Answer (score 1):

you may try as follows using parseFloat

```
if((parseFloat(within5Days) < 120 && parseFloat(within5Days) > -2)) {
     var within5DaysValue = within5Days;
     var within5DaysBoolean = true;
} else if ((parseFloat(within5Days) > 120) || parseFloat(within5Days) < -2)) {
     var within5DaysValue = within5Days;
     var within5DaysBoolean = false;
}
```

Comment: `Math.floor` returns a number or `NaN`